# port forwarding with putty (tunneling)

Tags: networking, ssh, putty, tunneling

I have a problem with my connection tunneling. So I'm using two ubuntu server virtual machines where the oracle xe (port 1521) is installed, lets call them uvm1 and uvm2. My goal is to create two tunnels for both servers and to map the ports to the host machine and make the connection to both database systems accessable. The port mapping should look like:

```
 vm name | vm port | host port
-------------------------------
 uvm1    | 1521    | 1521
 uvm2    | 1521    | 1522
-------------------------------
```

For tunnel creation I'm using putty on my windows machine: the configuration of putty for connection to the uvm1 looks like:

[image]

And the configuration of putty for connection to the uvm2 looks like:
[image]

I'm able to connect via ssh to both of the machines. The strage issue is that my tunneling for uvm1 works and for the uvm2 not.

Do anyone know how can I fix this strange issue?!

Cheers, Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you SSH into your ubuntu box, then the port forwarding should be:

```
source port: 1521
destination: <address-of-vm1>:1521
```

and

```
source port: 1522
destination: <address-of-vm2>:1521
```

You seem to be forwarding to 1521 and 1522 on the ubuntu box, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Or, if that's what he wanted he needs his ubuntu box Oracle instance to listen on 1522 as well as 1521.

Comment: Oh, yes I missunderstood the configuration settings for source and destination. Now it works fine for me!!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Cool. On StackOverflow it's somewhat customary to accept the answer in these cases.